Why Devtas don't visit earth anymore?
As I'm sure many many Texts mention of Devtas visiting earth either on some purpose or just flying around in their vimana until something catches their attention and they decend down to Earth.
My question is why don't we see or hear of Devtas visiting earth anymore? Is there a reason for it maybe something to do with Kaliyuga and impurity of today's world?

I) Your first question As I'm sure many many Texts mention of Devtas........My question is why don't we see or hear of Devtas visiting earth anymore?.
How do you so sure that devatas are not descending down onto the Earth, nowadays? Probably they are visible only to the eyes of highly evolved souls such as Yogis and Jnanis whom are hard to meet!
II) Your second and final question Is there a reason for it maybe something to do with Kaliyuga and impurity of today's world?
After the demise Sri Rāmāvatāra, Parashurāmāvatāra continued alone until birth of Krishnāvadāra in Dvāpara Yuga. There was an overlap and co-existence of Parashurāmāvatāra and Krishnāvadāra together until the demise of Bhagavan Krishna. Now, Parashurāmāvatāra is continuing alone until birth of Kalki avatāra. There will be an overlap and existence of Parashurāmāvatāra with Kalki avatāra concurrently until end of Kali Yuga.
Even Aśvatthāmā, son of Dronāchārya, has been roaming around the earth  in kali yuga with the curse of Sri Krishna!
My opinion is that they are still visiting the earth, in spite of Kaliyuga and impurity of today's world, but the point is that we are unable to see them.
Kalki Purana [Chapter-1, sloka-3] says:
May the Supreme Personality of Godhead, having assumed the form of
Kalki, who is the Supersoul of all living entities, establish the
eternal principles of religion Having appeared in a family of
brāhmanas, He will annihilate the sinful kings of Kali-yuga by the
fire of the poison emanating from His ferocious serpent-like hands
while riding on the back of an excellent horse of the Sindh province.
In this way, He will protect the pious and re-establish Satya-yuga.
 
- Kalki Purana [Chapter-1, sloka-3].


beautiful answer!
